# Meu SQLServer Express 2014 não mostra todas opções da instalação

Tags: sql, sql-server, instalador

Formatei o PC e estou tentando instalar o **SQLServer Express 2014** acompanhando um tutorial no youtube, porém quando chega a esse ponto da instação o meu não vem todas opções igual ao do vídeo.

**Obs:** Já instalei uma vez e simplesmente o sql não me deu opção de mudar minha instância, e não consegui logar colocando a instância padrão "**nome do PC\SQLEXPRESS**".

É a segunda vez que formato o PC por causa do SQL. Me ajudem!

**Baixei o SQL direto do site da Microsoft e estou usando Windows 10**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poste o link de onde você baixou o SQL Server. Possivelmente, a versão que você esteja baixando seja apenas o Management Studio, que te permite conectar à bases de dados já criadas.

Answer (score -1):

Pablo, a edição Express do SQL Server 2014 é disponibilizada em diferentes empacotamentos:

- Express (**SQLEXPR**): inclui apenas o mecanismo de banco de dados do
  SQL Server;
- Express with Tools (**SQLEXPRWT**): contém tudo o que é necessário
  para instalar e configurar o SQL Server como um servidor de banco de
  dados incluindo a versão completa do SQL Server 2014 Management
  Studio;
- Express with Advanced Services (**SQLEXPRADV**): contém todos os
  componentes do SQL Server Express, incluindo a versão completa do SQL
  Server 2014 Management Studio. Inclui também a pesquisa de
  texto completo e o Reporting Services.

Pela imagem à direita que postou, me parece que você utilizou o pacote SQLEXPR, que contém somente o *database engine*. Sugiro que acesse o link abaixo e selecione o pacote SQLEXPRADV, selecionando a arquitetura (32 ou 64 bits) e idioma desejados.

- [Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Service Pack 2 (SP2) Express](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-BR/download/details.aspx?id=53167)